# How to select Element Id inside attribute tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[Check Output and -->question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBV4E.png) .
I am new to programming in Bootstrap and JQuery. I want to know How to select the "id" of input element which is inside the attribute of another element.
I am using bootstrap for popover. when I click on `<a></a>` link it produce a popover but I want to get the element id inside **data-content** element i.e

This File from where i am selecting anchor and displaying popover. Now want to select the id inside the anchor tag but within **data-content** attribute of anchor element

```js
        $("a").popover(
            
        {
             delay:1000,
             html: true,

               

        })
```

This is Html Tag in which inside anchor tag i inserted bootstrap attribute and inside bootstrap **data-content** i inserted the html elemnt  and want to select the ID of that input element inside data-content attribute of anchr tag.

How to do it?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Username:"  data-content='<input id="Uname" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="You are Successfull!!!!" type="text"/><input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" />'></a>
```

How to do it?
Anyone Can Suggest

Comment: You'll need to escape the `<` and `>` characters inside the string

Comment: I've never seen this practice before . What are you trying to accomplish as your ultimate goal may I ask? There's most likely a much quicker way of doing this .

Comment: I inserted the Screenshot on start of question if you see the Screenshot ... you get understand. the on anchor tag displaying a popover and inside popover  there is textbox and button i want to select id and perform the action s with them....

Answer (score 2):

Try instantiating a new jquery object for the data-content element, like so:

```js
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var content = $(this).data('content');
        var input = $(content);
        window.alert(input.attr('id'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Username:"  data-content='<input id="Uname" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="You are Successfull!!!!" type="text"/><input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" />'>Click me!</a>
```

Updated with active snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are in control of the id.  If that is the case, then simply add the Id to the containing element:

```
<a href="#" 
   data-toggle="popover" 
   title="Username:"  
   data-target-id="#uname"
   data-content='<input id="uname" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="You are Successfull!!!!" type="text"/><input id="btnEdit" type="button" value="Edit" />'>
</a>
```

Then when you initialize you could do:

```
$anchor.popover({
  html: true,
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
   var $anchor = $(this);
   var id = $anchor.data('target-id');
   $(id).SomeOtherMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value of the data-content attribute, create that element temporarily and then get its id! Assuming it may not be the best solution, but I think it should work.